# Possible to check string format and extract substrings at the same time using one NSRegularExpression?

Tags: swift, regex

**TL;DR:** I would like to parse a text file and check each line to have a correct format / syntax. Additionally I would like to extract some substrings. Is it possible to do this at the same time using only one `NSRegularExpression`?

**Details:**
Assume each line should contain exactly one "sentence" containing different words, for example "Word1 word2 LastWord."

The regex `^((\w+) ?)+\.$` would match the string and thus check the format. However, it would return these three capture groups / ranges:
`Word1 word2 LastWord.`, `LastWord` and `LastWord` while I would expect / require it to return `Word1 word2 LastWord.`, `Word1`, `word2` and `LastWord` instead.

Of course it would be no problem to use two RegEx, one to check the format and one to extract the words. However, I would like to learn if I Am doing something wrong or if this is a limitation of RegEx in general?

Comment: No, it is not possible since the groups do not contain all the captures, only the last capture is kept. But you can use another approach. You can use a multiple matching approach only when the string conforms to your format, e.g. `(?:\G(?!^) |^(?=\w+(?: \w+)*\.$))(\w+)` (see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/4yK2Ti/1)). Or `(?:\G(?!^)\s+|^(?=\w+(?:\s+\w+)*\.$))(\w+)` (if you allow one or more whitespaces between the words).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Very nice approach! Thanks for sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to do that with Swift ICU-based regex, since the capture groups do not contain all the captures, they only keep the last capture.

However, you can use another approach. You can use **multiple matching approach** and implement the validation in the form of a positive lookahead at the start. Then, you'd only match and capture the consequent parts of the string that passed the text.

An example regex for the current scenario would be

```
(?:\G(?!^) |^(?=\w+(?: \w+)*\.$))(\w+)
(?:\G(?!^)\s+|^(?=\w+(?:\s+\w+)*\.$))(\w+)
```

The first regex only allows a single regular space between words, the second one  allows one or more whitespaces between the words.

See the [regex #1 demo](https://regex101.com/r/4yK2Ti/1) and [regex #2 demo](https://regex101.com/r/4yK2Ti/2).

*Details*

- `(?:\G(?!^)\s+|^(?=\w+(?:\s+\w+)*\.$))` - either of the two:

  - `\G(?!^)\s+` - one or more whitespaces only if there was a successful previous match (note that `\G` matches either start of the string or at the end of the preceding match, so the `(?!^)` lookahead is a must)
  - `|` - or
  - `^(?=\w+(?:\s+\w+)*\.$)` - the start of string *only* if - immediately to the right, there are one or more word chars, and then zero or more repetitions of one or more whitespaces + one or more word chars, and finally a dot at the end of the string (so this is where validation occurs)
- `(\w+)` - Group 1: one or more word chars.

To get the results you need, you'd need to get Group 1 values.